# Where to store the chalk (magnesium carbonate) when training parkour?

Tags: rock-climbing, parkour

It's been a while since I've practiced parkour and I want to start practicing again, the problem is that I've lost completely my capacity to hold a good grip. I've never used chalk to practice, but when I watched a video of the "[Human Monkey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPN3gLVDsOY)" I noticed that he had on his hands some kind of powder and a bag hanging from his belt. So, I was thinking that I can use chalk to keep a good grip, at least until I get back in shape.

Where can I put the chalk while practicing parkour? is there some specialized equipment for that? or would just a small fanny pack do the job?

Comment: As a possible alternative, you might look at gloves with gripping surfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, it's just chalk, like you see gymnasts, weight lifters, rock climbers, etc., use. A fanny pack would be ok to hold it, but I imagine it would leak powder everywhere.

They do make specialized bags, but you may have the same problem with chalk leaking everywhere when doing parkour.

[Here is a link to the REI page](http://www.rei.com/c/chalk-and-chalk-bags?r=c&ir=category%3Achalk-and-chalk-bags&page=1) showing some of the chalks/bags that are available.

Comment: Coming from a bouldering background, if you use chalk balls as opposed to loose powder, then there's not much leakage from chalk bags. The main problem is if you land on them, otherwise, they survive the rough and tumble quite well. (Small note, don't use a karabiner to attach it to yourself, because if you land on one of them, they DO hurt)